# Create a list to share?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an app that saves data in a .csv file, in the download folder.

I am trying to create a list of this data (from the csv file), that could be shared (through any options chosen from the user).

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.readingValue()
    }
    async readingValue() {
    // get a list of files and directories in the main bundle  :ExternalStorageDirectoryPath 
    const elementiDirectory = await RNFS.readDir(RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/Download/') 
    const pathElementi = elementiDirectory.map(e => e.path);
    //console.log("filter " + pathElementi)
    const pathCSV = pathElementi.filter(path => {
      const reg = /sd\d+\.csv/;
      return reg.test(path);
    });
    console.log("risultati " + pathCSV)
    this.setState({risultati : pathCSV});
  }

  onShare = async () => {
    console.log("Dentro OnShare")
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message:
          'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React',
        url: this.state.risultati
      });

      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
          console.log("Condivisione OK.")
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
              <Text>{this.state.risultati}</Text>
              <Button onPress={this.onShare} title="Share" />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

With the function `async readingValue()` I found the path of the data. 
For example, this.state.risultati will show

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/nameofthefile.csv
```

While with the onShare function I create the options to share.

Now it works with one file in the Download folder.

How can I do to create a list of values that could be shared?

Like:

File1 | sharebutton

File2 | sharebutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve in this way:

```
render() {
  const RisultatoDaCondividere = this.state.risultati.map(singoloRisultato => {
    return(
      <View>
      <Text>
        {singoloRisultato} 
      </Text>
      <Button onPress={this.onShare} title="Share" />
      </View>
    )
  })

    return (
            <View>
              {RisultatoDaCondividere}              
            </View>
        );
    }
```